# Connecting to Pi via SSH over WiFi - Does WiFi shutoff after no useage?

Tags: networking, ssh, wifi

When I plug my Pi in and boot up, I am able to connect over the air with SSH at 192.168.1.100 (static IP address set in /etc/network/interfaces).

However if I boot up my Pi and leave it for 1-2 hours or longer, when trying to connect to my Pi with SSH at the same address, I always get the SSH error

```
Network error: Connection timed out
```

It seems as though the WiFi may shut down on the Pi after no useage for a certain period, however looking at the Pi physically, the lights seem the same as they are when directly booting up - Flashing WiFi Usb and other solid PI board LEDS.

Comment: can you connect a screen and keyboard to ensure the Pi is still operating ?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` connections timeout after a period of inactivity. This is unlikely to be the Pi, but the client timeout, although the network connection may timeout on inactivity. (My Mac remains connected to my Pis for hours - until the Mac goes to sleep).

You can set `ssh timeout` on the Pi, but you would be better to do this on your ssh client (you don't tells us which OS or client you are using). This causes to client to send a keep alive message at regular intervals, and it will only disconnect if no response is received.

Comment: @KerryJames is talking about making new connections not existing connections timing out. FYI I leave ssh connections to my Pi open for days at a time without them timing out (host machine is not allowed to sleep).